# Sometimes cursor jumps to start of line in bash prompt

Tags: bash

I have my bash prompt as defined in following script -

```
#!/bin/bash

if tput setaf 1 &> /dev/null; then
    tput sgr0; # reset colors
    bold=$(tput bold);
    reset=$(tput sgr0);
    black=$(tput setaf 235)
    red=$(tput setaf 1)
    green=$(tput setaf 142)
    yellow=$(tput setaf 214)
    blue=$(tput setaf 66)
    purple=$(tput setaf 175)
    cyan=$(tput setaf 37)
    gray=$(tput setaf 246)
    white=$(tput setaf 223)
    orange=$(tput setaf 208)
else
    bold='';
    reset="\e[0m";
    black="\e[1;30m";
    blue="\e[1;34m";
    cyan="\e[1;36m";
    green="\e[1;32m";
    orange="\e[1;33m";
    purple="\e[1;35m";
    red="\e[1;31m";
    violet="\e[1;35m";
    white="\e[1;37m";
    yellow="\e[1;33m";
fi;

# Highlight the user name when logged in as root.
if [[ "$USER" == "root" ]]; then
    userStyle="$red";
else
    userStyle="$orange";
fi;

# Highlight the hostname when connected via SSH.
if [[ "$SSH_TTY" ]]; then
    hostStyle="$green";
else
    hostStyle="$gray";
fi;

dirStyle="$cyan"

function prompt_command {
    ret_code=$?
    # Are we running in a shell invoked from Vim?
    if [[ "$VIM" ]]; then
        vim="(Vim) "
    else
        vim=""
    fi

    # Did last command return non-zero value?
    if [ "$ret_code" != 0 ]; then
        ret_str="\[$red\]$ret_code>"
    else
        ret_str="\[$green\]$"
    fi

    PS1="\[$userStyle\]\u \[$reset\]at \[$hostStyle\]\H \[$reset\]in \[$dirStyle\]\w\n\[$yellow\]$vim$ret_str\[$reset\] "
}
export PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_command
export PS2="\[$blue\]continue -> \[$reset\]"
```

It's really simple, just username, hostname, current directory and couple of variables - one to check if shell was invoked from vim and other is return code of last command.

Sometimes the cursor jumps to start of line when I'm trying tab completion. I've not been able to find a pattern when exactly this happens.

This is how the prompt looks like -

```
rogandhi at sjc-ads-253 in ~/tools
$
rogandhi at sjc-ads-253 in ~/tools
$ adsf
-bash: adsf: command not found
rogandhi at sjc-ads-253 in ~/tools
127>
```

Looks like this when shell is invoked from vim -

```
rogandhi at sjc-ads-253 in ~/tools
(Vim) $
rogandhi at sjc-ads-253 in ~/tools
(Vim) $ asdf
bash: asdf: command not found
rogandhi at sjc-ads-253 in ~/tools
(Vim) 127>
```

Following is the output of `declare -p PS1`

```
rogandhi at sjc-ads-253 in ~/tools
$ declare -p PS1
declare -- PS1="\\[\\]\\u \\[\\]at \\[\\]\\H \\[\\]in \\[\\]\\w\\n\\[\\]\\[\\]\$\\[\\] "
```

Any ideas? How do I go about debugging this behavior?

Comment: Why are there brackets around the newline?

Comment: Does that happen also when you set `PS1=">>> "` ?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The cursor jump happens less frequently when I added the brackets around `\n`.

Comment: @hek2mgl no issues with a simpler prompt like one you suggested.

Comment: This is BashFAQ #53: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/053

Comment: ...btw, if you want to make your question *complete* (per the MCVE spec), don't just link to the code, but actually provide your prompt as it's set up by it. Adding the output of `declare -p PS1` to the question would help its completeness; while links that add info are welcome, questions that can't be answered without them (and become useless should the link break) are not.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I've gone through that FAQ already. I think I've got all the non-printable characters covered. I also added the information you asked for.

Comment: You might add your own answer w/ the content currently given in the edit. (Hopefully the PS1 shown in the question is the one that reproduces the problem? If not -- as the `$` there appears to be escaped -- it's... not exactly a question, with the problem already edited out).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy updated the question with actual script with the issue and posted the Edit as answer. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the `$` in line `ret_str="\[$green\]$"` is not escaped.

Escaping the `$` with a `\` fixed the problem.

Fix:

`ret_str="\[$green\]\$"`